# Table-valued Functions - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Begin'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-function

I am trying to write a function in SQL, that executes another function depending on the condition. but I am not able to fix the error here.

> fn_GetSpecialLastCurrencyRateByDate, Line - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Begin'

```
CREATE FUNCTION [BCF].[fn_GetSpecialLastCurrencyRateByDate]
(   
    @SkinId INT,
    @CurrencyIdFrom char(3),
    @CurrencyIdTo char(3),
    @EndDate datetime
)
RETURNS
TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    CurrencyId char(3),
    ToCurrencyId char(3),
    Rate decimal(24,18),
    Date date
)
AS
Begin
    If (not exists( Select TOP 1 Id, CurrencyId,ToCurrencyId ,Rate , Date date
        From BCF.SkinCurrencyRate
        Where SkinId = @SkinId and CurrencyId = @CurrencyIdFrom AND ToCurrencyId = ISNULL(@CurrencyIdTo, 'EUR')  and Date<=@EndDate
        Order By Date desc))
    BEGIN
        return Select Id, CurrencyId,ToCurrencyId ,Rate , Date date from [BCF].fn_GetLastCurrencyRateByDate(@CurrencyIdFrom, @CurrencyIdTo, @EndDate)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        RETURN (
        Select TOP 1 Id, CurrencyId,ToCurrencyId ,Rate , Date date
        From BCF.SkinCurrencyRate
        Where SkinId = @SkinId and CurrencyId = @CurrencyIdFrom AND ToCurrencyId = ISNULL(@CurrencyIdTo, 'EUR')  and Date<=@EndDate
        Order By Date desc)
    END
end
GO
```

Comment: This looks like you're trying to combine the syntax of a multi-line table-value function and an inline table-value function (which will never work). You have 2 `RETURN` statements here, which makes no sense. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: if the condition in the if body is true, execute this line: return Select Id, CurrencyId,ToCurrencyId ,Rate , Date date from [BCF].fn_GetLastCurrencyRateByDate(@CurrencyIdFrom, @CurrencyIdTo, @EndDate) .. else execute the else statement

Comment: That would create a multi-line table-value function, @RaduGheorghiu , which are *known* to perform poorly. The OP should really be using an inline TVF.

Comment: @Larnu So how can i modify this function so it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare your table name like below

```
RETURNS @Result
```

Then you need to insert into `@Result` table instead.

Your entire code should be like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [BCF].[fn_GetSpecialLastCurrencyRateByDate]
(   
    @SkinId INT,
    @CurrencyIdFrom char(3),
    @CurrencyIdTo char(3),
    @EndDate datetime
)
RETURNS @Result
TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    CurrencyId char(3),
    ToCurrencyId char(3),
    Rate decimal(24,18),
    Date date
)
AS
Begin
    If (not exists( Select TOP 1 Id, CurrencyId,ToCurrencyId ,Rate , Date date
        From BCF.SkinCurrencyRate
        Where SkinId = @SkinId and CurrencyId = @CurrencyIdFrom AND ToCurrencyId = ISNULL(@CurrencyIdTo, 'EUR')  and Date<=@EndDate
        Order By Date desc))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Result 
        Select Id, CurrencyId,ToCurrencyId ,Rate , Date date from [BCF].fn_GetLastCurrencyRateByDate(@CurrencyIdFrom, @CurrencyIdTo, @EndDate)

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Result
        Select TOP 1 Id, CurrencyId,ToCurrencyId ,Rate , Date date
        From BCF.SkinCurrencyRate
        Where SkinId = @SkinId and CurrencyId = @CurrencyIdFrom AND ToCurrencyId = ISNULL(@CurrencyIdTo, 'EUR')  and Date<=@EndDate
        Order By Date desc
    END

    RETURN;
end
GO
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Ardavazt

Comment: I am getting this error now: Procedure fn_GetSpecialLastCurrencyRateByDate, Line 37 [Batch Start Line 0]
The last statement included within a function must be a return statement.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look @Ardavazt